# Splitting numbers of a cell and adding them together in an ArrayFormula on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

My question is how can I have digits of a cell added together in an array formula format, in that

```
12 | -> 3      //(result: 3 = 1 + 2)
14 | -> 5
46 | -> 10
11 | -> 2
53 | -> 8
```

And let’s just say the values 12, 14, 46 on are on column A and the answered would be B.

Comment: so the result will be 18? (3+5+10) ?

Comment: no, i am looking for a way to make 12 into 3 by making 12->1+2=3, via an array formula. The only thing that has worked for me is 


=REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"\D+", "")

however, that is only in a single row instance - changing it into
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"\D+", ""))


does not calculate all values in the A column for me, but rather only the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **up to 2 digits:**


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)=2, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1), ))
  ```
- **up to 3 digits:**


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)=2, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=3, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1), )))
  ```
- **up to 4 digits:**


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)=2, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=3, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=4, MID   (A1:A, 1, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 3, 1) 
                              + MID   (A1:A, 4, 1), ))))
  ```
- **added single digit support:**


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)=1,        A1:A,
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=2, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=3, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                IF(LEN(A1:A)=4, MID   (A1:A, 1, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                              + MID   (A1:A, 3, 1) 
                              + MID   (A1:A, 4, 1), )))))
  ```
- **limit array for only first 3 ocurances:**


  ```
  =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)=1,        A1:A,
                                IF(LEN(A1:A)=2, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                                IF(LEN(A1:A)=3, LEFT  (A1:A, 1)
                                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                                              + RIGHT (A1:A, 1),
                                IF(LEN(A1:A)=4, MID   (A1:A, 1, 1)
                                              + MID   (A1:A, 2, 1)
                                              + MID   (A1:A, 3, 1) 
                                              + MID   (A1:A, 4, 1), ))))), 3, 1)
  ```